# Vagrant: Mounting Home Directory via NFS

Tags: vagrant

I'm running multiple VMs with the same operating system and I'd like to share my dotfiles between them. In setting up my vagrant file I originally tried:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/Erik/VirtualMachines/Home", "/home/vagrant", nfs: true
```

While I was able to log in with password, the SSH login failed - most likely becaue my home directory had the files owned by "503" and not "vagrant". When I changed this to  just

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/Erik/VirtualMachines/Home", "/home/vagrant"
```

Everything worked as expected, including SSH login. Is there anyway to get this to behave properly using NFS?

Answer (score -1):

I've not tested this but you may be able to match UID/GID between host and guest. If you're just looking to share .files it seems like the effort and possible issues wouldn't be worth it though.